# setting up Spring in Eclipse - context initialization failure

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I am trying to set up Eclipse (being a newbie in Java and Eclipse and Spring) following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm) and when trying to run a simple HelloWorld.java, I get this error in my console

```
bře 28, 2020 6:58:18 ODP. org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorld' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld]: Is the constructor accessible?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils (in module spring.beans) cannot access class com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld (in module HelloSpring) because module HelloSpring does not export com.tutorialspoint to module spring.beans
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorld' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld]: Is the constructor accessible?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils (in module spring.beans) cannot access class com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld (in module HelloSpring) because module HelloSpring does not export com.tutorialspoint to module spring.beans
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
    at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at HelloSpring/com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld]: Is the constructor accessible?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils (in module spring.beans) cannot access class com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld (in module HelloSpring) because module HelloSpring does not export com.tutorialspoint to module spring.beans
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils (in module spring.beans) cannot access class com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld (in module HelloSpring) because module HelloSpring does not export com.tutorialspoint to module spring.beans
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:376)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:647)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    ... 15 more
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong?

my code in HelloWorld.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }
   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}
```

my code in MainApp.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      obj.getMessage();
   }
}
```

Comment: First I'd like to recommend against tutorials from tutorialpoint. Most of them are of very dubious quality. Stick to official tutorials or reputable sources. Secondly, the tutorial was designed with Java 8 (or before) in mind, and you're running it with Java 9 or higher. You'd probably need to tune the module access rights, but I can't tell you how that should be done off the top of my head.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you supply us with the java code.
But, based on the errors I believe there is a corrupted file when you were installing the program. 
Make sure there are no restrictions on the computer you are using and reinstall the program
Use this [tutoria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDfnBVGskm8)l instead.
Hope That Helped!

Comment: No it's not. It's because of the module system introduced in Java 9.

Comment: I forgot about that

Comment: Thank you both, I just reinstalled from the marketplace and it works fine (also because I could not find what to do with those changed module access rights)

Answer (score 0):

ok, after some more fiddling I found where the problem was.

1) the Spring libraries must be manually added under the classpath, not modulepath

2) the xml file must be place directly in the src folder and not in the package with java files.

[image]